# Excel Query missing rows

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I'm trying to setup tables in a spreadsheet as using query, from file, xlsx

On the source data there are 16,149 rows and after the import I only get 16,107 rows.

I've dummy'd down the import as much as possible I think:

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Users\myfile.xlsx"), null, true),
    Sheet1_Sheet = Source{[Item="Sheet1",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Sheet1_Sheet)
in
    #"Promoted Headers"
```

Is there any way to debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok figured it out. problem was I was ignoring an error message when I ran the query that was a result of the new file missing one column that was present in the old data.
Net-net, the new file never got imported and that's why the row counts were different.